# strange situation when running ranger as: "terminal -e ranger"

Tags: i3, ranger

when I open ranger in the terminal as: `ranger`, everything is Ok. However, when I open it for example as: `alacritty -e ranger` the strange situation happens (1st figure). for fixing it i have to decrease the size of terminal font (2nd figure). this situation doesn't happen in urxvt and st but happens in gnome-terminal, xfce-terminal, and alacritty. my wm is i3 but to check I also tried it on vanilla xmonad but I didn't had this problem. wonder if the problem is i3 or ranger or those terminals.

btw I don't know what this situation is called.

`Os: debian buster/sid`
(I had this issue in archlinux too)

`window manager: i3`

[image: ranger with my default terminal size]

[image: ranger with small font size]

Comment: I'm using alacritty on arch with i3 but I can't reproduce your problem. Try to check your TERM in ranger (`:shell -w echo $TERM`)

Comment: it gives me: `xterm-256color`

Comment: also in my alacritty config I have a section `env:` which under it, I've set  `TERM: xterm-256color`. when I comment it, and do `:shell -w echo $TERM`, it gives me `alacritty` and it (unsetting the variable) didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I just solved similar-looking problems by using `alacritty -e env COLUMNS= LINES= ranger`.  I learned that trick from https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/4560#issuecomment-763204194

Comment: Currently I switched to artixlinux and I don't have this problem there. If this trick solved this issue for you, please write an answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding these lines to `config.fish` solved the issue for me.

```
set --unexport COLUMNS
set --unexport LINES
```

Credit for workaround goes to [@faho](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/7707#issuecomment-777239241)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Perhaps you could add some explanation how this works to solve the OPs problem.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to this nameless problem. please fell free to edit the title and question. The title is not helpful I guess and I have no idea what to write instead.